# Updating Button Label When Detecting Number of Open Divs Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I almost got my function to work but I'm missing some ingredient.

1. I have 3 boxes with their own toggle open close button.
2. I have an Open All / Close All button that detects the number of open boxes, and switches its text label from 'Open All' to 'Close All' when all 3 boxes are open.

It works fine, except **if you start out by clicking on the (red) Open All button after loading the page** — and then manually close each individual box — and toggle them open again. Then the red Open / Close all button doesn't detect the opened boxes, and its text label doesn't switch from Open All to Close All.

I know it's unlikely that anyone would use the system this way, but I just want to understand why it stops detecting the number of open boxes.

http://codepen.io/StrengthandFreedom/pen/Yyemqa

```
    // Open/close all boxes 
    $('.show-hide').on('click', function(){
      event.preventDefault();
    $('.box').siblings().toggleClass('is-visible',
    $('.box').length != $('.box.is-visible').length);
    $('.open-all').toggleClass('hide-text');
    $('.close-all').toggleClass('show-text');  
    });  


    // Toggle boxes individually   
    $('.toggle-button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next('.box').toggleClass('is-visible');

    // Count number of open (visible) boxes  
    var numOfVisible = $('.is-visible').length; 

    // if open boxes equal 3, switch button label
    if (numOfVisible === 3) {
    $('.open-all').addClass('hide-text');
    $('.close-all').addClass('show-text');
    }
    // otherwise do the opposite
   else {
   $('.open-all').removeClass('hide-text');
   $('.close-all').removeClass('show-text');    

    }
   });
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to use

```
var numOfVisible = $('.box.is-visible').length;
```

instead of

```
var numOfVisible = $('.is-visible').length;
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYmPaq)

Comment: Of course that was it, works great now, thank you @Mohamed-Yousef :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epMJRz

This is the change on jquery code i made to make it work:

```
$('.show-hide').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
    $('.toggle-button').trigger('click'); 
});
```

Had to refork it to resolve a bug now its perfect